# Cannot load laravel blade.php file from javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I downloaded a [template](https://github.com/Morrolan/golgi) that i want to use in laravel. My issue is that I rename every *.html to *.blade.php but laravel does not render the routes. Please find below the codes

Original index.html (Portion of code)

```
  <div class="navbarmenu"></div>
                <!--Load Navbar Menu In App.js loadhtml function-->
                <!--Begin Container-->
```

The navbar menu is found in a separate file which gets loaded by a javascript file. Part of the coding included

```
function loadhtml() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("mail.blade.php") > -1) {
        $(".toc").load("partials/loadmailmenu.blade.php", function () {
            $(".ui.accordion").accordion();
        });
        $(".navbarmenu").load("partials/loadnavbar.blade.php", function () {
            hamburger();
            $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
        });
```

Things I tried which did not work
1. The converted files were stored in public/partials/*.blade.php 
2. The converted files were stored in resources/views/partials/*.blade.php

Thank you

Comment: Php and blade are serverside and thus cannot be rendered by the javascript frontend.

Comment: You need to load the route, not the blade file.